# AUI Custom required validation does not work if val length is 0

Tags: validation, liferay, liferay-aui

I'm trying to make conditionally requiring field,I tryed this one:

```
    <aui:validator name="custom" errorMessage="custom">
function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
     var cond = document.getElementById("something").value;
    if(val.length == 0 && cond == "something") {
        return false;
    } else {
        return true;
    }
}
```

But the problem is that this function does not occur for length 0,only if I put something in text field.

This is works :

```
 <aui:validator name="required">
           function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
     var cond = document.getElementById("something").value;
    if(val.length == 0 && cond == "something") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
    </aui:validator>
```

But then I have label required.

How I can trigger custom validation if length is 0?

Answer (score 0):

For details about liferay aui validation you can follow [this tutorial](http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2013/12/liferay-aui-validator.html)

I have tried this and following code is working fine for me:

```
<aui:form name="fm2" action="" method="post">
<aui:input name="age" value='' label="Age">
    <aui:validator  name="custom"  errorMessage="You must have 18 years or more" >
    function (val, fieldNode, ruleValue) {
    var result = false;
    if (val >=18) {
    result = true;
    }
    return result;
    }
    </aui:validator>
    <aui:validator name="required" />
</aui:input>
<aui:button type="submit" name="save" value="Save" />
```